# Hibernate Exception -Lock Acquistion Exception : could not execute native bulk manipulation queries

Tags: hibernate, db2

I am getting a hibernate exception Lock Acquistion Exception, when I'm accessing two jobs concurrently in production environment . 
while the tables in both the jobs are different and I am not implementing synchronization too.
Please help!

> WARN [hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter]  - SQL Error: -911,
>   SQLState: 40001 [2/14/19 12:41:04:233 IST] 0000022e SystemOut     O
>   2019-02-14 12:41:04,233
>
> ERROR [hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] 
>   - The current transaction has been rolled back because of a deadlock or timeout.  Reason code "68".. SQLCODE=-911, SQLSTATE=40001,
>   DRIVER=3.62.57
>
> [2/14/19 12:41:04:233 IST] 0000022e SystemOut     O 2019-02-14
>   12:41:04,233  ERROR [dao.execution.daoImpl]  -
>   org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException: could not execute
>   native bulk manipulation query

Comment: FYI Reason code 68 on a SQL911N is a "The transaction was rolled back due to a lock timeout."

Comment: @PaulVernon Thanks ! Do you have any idea that  whether it is occurring mainly at database level or Java Application Code level ?

Comment: You can ask for database trace logs from dba which will be helpful in detecting the deadlocked process.Generally one transaction is choosen as deadlock victim and is rolledbacked .Without looking at code and data model it is very tough to guess.But database trace files are good place to start with.

Comment: Thanks @user06062019 , will start from there only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the suggestions at this page

> Resolving lock timeout problems

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.trb.doc/doc/t0055072.html

Comment: Thanks @paul , it can be of great help, will check and post the solution to it .